# why is scenario.getName() in @Before hook, only returning the last scenario name?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I'm creating a framework in Selenium webdriver with Cucumber & TestNG and for reporting part, I'm using Extent Report.

In the @Before hook, I want to take the name of each and every scenarios. So I'm using **scenario.getName()** method. So for 4 scenarios, I suppose to get 4 different scenario names by this method, but everytime I'm getting only the last scenario name. For an example: Below is my feature file:
[image]

And Below is my Step Definition method where I'm using @Before hook.
[image]

*Note: In @Before hook, I used **cucumber.api.Scenario**, because there are two Scenario classes, one is from Extent Report and another is from cucumber.api, so I imported the first one and used the full fledged name for the second one.*

Now, for the S.O.P function in @Before hook, it should print the scenario names one by one for each iteration. But, every time I'm getting only the last scenario name. Where am I doing wrong? 
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The first 3 scenario outlines are ignored. The reason is that they do not have any examples table. Only the last scenario outline has an examples table attached to it and is run.

The last scenario outline has the name "User Login" which is repeated 4 times for each row of the Examples table.

Copy the examples table to each of the scenario outline.

```
Scenario Outline: <title>
Given User is on....

Examples
|username |....| title |
...............| valid login |
```

Comment: I think you should specify that instead of copying the ENTIRE table to the other three scenarios, it needs to only copy the header line and the one line pertaining to each scenario to that scenario, otherwise it's going to run four times for each of the four scenarios.

Comment: @BillHileman Yeah makes sense. Guess I missed that. Actually on closer look, only one scenario outline is required. The steps in all 4 scenario outlines are the same. The name can also be moved into the examples table.

Comment: Thanks Grasshopper and Bill Hileman. It worked when I copied the example table with the header line and respective data into each scenario outline. @Grasshopper , you said in your last comment, The name can also be moved into the examples table. What do you mean by that?

Comment: @BongCule u can just use one scenario outline. Check the updated answer.